# The seven letter word

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, poetry

> Don't worry, I won't let you overflow.
>
> Is anyone operating on you? I won't let you overflow by that.
>
> Do you want to link yourself? I won't let you overflow by that.
>
> Is there an expression of the unspecified? I won't let you overflow by that.
>
> Is someone really crossing the line? I won't let you overflow by that.
>
> Do you have some clefts? I will mend them and you won't overflow.

What am I?

Subtle Hint:

> Do you want to answer for an action? I am the action.

Moderate Hint:

> Just let me go. You are the content.

Decisive Hint:

> One letter modified, I am a language.

Comment: Either you’re *perfect*, *special*, or just *nothing*.

Comment: I think the answer is rot13(Pybfher) but I don't have the mathematical knowledge to explain it so I don't want to write an answer that is based only on a hint.

Comment: @JS1 Correct. You should search that on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Guess based on the latest hint:

> Closure (one letter away from Clojure which is a programming language)

Explanation:

*Don't worry, I won't let you overflow.

Is anyone operating on you? I won't let you overflow by that.*

> A closure under an operation can even include unbounded sets as long as the specified operation always produces a member of that set

*Do you want to link yourself? I won't let you overflow by that.*

> **Transitive Closure** makes a relation ("link yourself") transitive.

*Is there an expression of the unspecified? I won't let you overflow by that.*

> **Algebraic Closure** is the set of roots of all polynomials ("expression of the unspecified").

*Is someone really crossing the line? I won't let you overflow by that.*

> **Closure** as in **Topology** adds a boundary ("line") to a set.

*Do you have some clefts? I will mend them and you won't overflow.*

> **Convex Closure** makes a set convex by adding points in its "clefts."

Hints 1 and 2 seems straight forward. As for hint 3:

> Clojure is a programming language that run on the JVM (Java virtual machine).

Comment: I feel that’s the answer too; If you don’t mind, may I improve your answer based on what I know in Math? I can explain each of the clues provided in the question. Or should I rather post it as a separate answer instead?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Sure you can go ahead and edit my answer.

Comment: Sure thing! Done.

Comment: Since your answer was the closest, I edited your answer to the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

My guess:

> Modulus

Explanation:

> A modulus will not allow its operands to overflow. Modular arithmetic allows basic arithmetic operations. All values from a modulus (mod $x$) are bounded (between 0 and $|x| - 1$), so no one can actually “cross the line.”

Comment: If this isn't it, I'll be shocked.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to guess:

> Warning, as in an error trap message in a computer program.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> Program.

As in

> A computer program.

Because

> Programs ensure that whatever errors you make, the buffer will not overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a

> Barrier

Because

> I don't have the knowledge yet to fit all of the clues, but a barrier can stop things from overflowing.
>  Language Hint: On Wikipedia,( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_language ) Carrier is apparently spoken in BC, Canada.